# Making a copy constructor that makes a deep copy of the input object (using arrays)

Tags: c++, copy-constructor

I need to make a deep copy of an input object using a copy constructor. I'm very much stuck...

my code so far:

```
class stringCS   
{   
public:    
     stringCS();
     stringCS(const stringCS &other);

private:
     char *input;
};


stringCS::stringCS(const stringCS &other)
{
}
```

How do I go about making the deep copy? I know I need to use a for loop to loop through all the characters in the array to copy it into another array with the null terminator at the end, but I don't understand the parameter or where the original array comes from.

Edit:

By no means am I looking for someone to just give me the code. I'm looking for something more along the lines of pseudocode/answers to my questions. I don't know how to begin copying because I don't understand the parameter.

Answer (score 1):

This should do the job:

```
class stringCS   
{
private:
    string input;
public:    
    stringCS(const string& other) : input(other)
    {
    }
};
```

If you need to use cstrings this skeleton might put you on track

```
class stringCS   
{
public:    
    stringCS();
    stringCS(const stringCS &other);
    {
        // a) input is a pointer, allocate enough memory
        // you will need to know the size of other (strlen() + 1)
        ...

        // b) copy character by character from `other.input` to `input` in a loop
        // do not forget the final '\0'
        ...
    }
private:
    char *input;
};
```

Comment: I'm sure that would work, but I actually need to use a for loop to make a copy into an array...

Comment: I am not sure that giving you the finished solution is a good thing, so I'll provide some hints: a) you need to allocate enough memory to store the characters of the string (including the final '\0'. b) You could copy character by character from the string to the char* (and add a final '\0' since the string does not contain one). I hope that helps.

Comment: Okay. I have code for this, but I just don't want to put it up...is there a way I can send it to you privately? I'm getting an error that says 'no operator '[]' matches these operands' can i not use other[index]? Is it not an array???

Comment: @Rachel: You need to use other.input[index]. other[index] tries to apply the index to the class itself, which by default is undefined. To make this work, you'd have to write your own operator[]. Anyway, I don't understand the secrecy here. This is something that takes a lot of time when you're still on your first steps of learning C++, but with some experience, it's easy to write in a few minutes. Or is it an assignment and you're trying to hide the solution from your classmates?

Comment: That's what I didn't understand! I used other.input[index] and that solved my problem...thanks!